# Outdated calendar entry on lock screen

Tags: lumia, calendars, lock-screen, nokia-lumia-535

I'm using Lumia 535 with Google account and (default) setting of displaying nearest calendar event in the bottom part of my lock screen.

Even though my phone syncs details with Google account (e-mails, contacts and calendar events) on regular basis (every 15 minutes plus sometimes manually) and even though system calendar is up to date, I can see some completely outdated entry on my lock screen.

Most time it displays event, that I no longer have in my calendar. After most (manual or automatic) account sync, I can see that this lock-screen calendar entry does not change. And even if it does, it changes to another "ghost" event, that I had in my calendar for example yesterday or edited it (in my Gmail) and changed its title like about hours ago.

For the sake of testing, I have even installed extra calenda ("SimpleCalendar"), next to system one, to double check, if everything is OK. Both calendars shows up-to-date entries in my Google calendars and correctly synces with all recent changes. Only lock-screen remains the problem.

Does anyone recall similar situation and know, what can be causing it or how to fix it? My wife has Lumia 735 with the same software version (Denim) and for the past ten months, she has been using it, we have never encountered such weird situation.

Answer (score 2):

My lumia 830 was doing that too. My lock screen calendar was showing only an old entry. 
Rectified by pinning calendar to start screen. No problems since.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was just a temporal Calendar or screen lock "hangout".

To resolve this and similar case, consider following options:

- perform full phone restart (i.e. turn off completely and turn it on back),
- force account Google sync (after restart),
- delete Google account, add it again and force sync.

In my case, first step solved the problem, but I heard others forced to follow other steps.

From my other experience (problems with Weather application not refreshing lock screen), there is also another advice -- make sure, that any application, that changes lock screen *is installed to Phone*, not to SD card. Moving such applications to SD card may influence, how they deal with lock screen.